# Method is not returning values that is annoted with @Cacheable

Tags: caching

```
@Cacheable(value = cacheName", keyGenerator = "cacheKeyGenerator")
public List<Rate> findByStateNameAndConsolidationKey(String stateName,RatesConsolidationKey consolidationKey) {
LOG.info("Method called not using cache   ");
List<TaxRate> listOfRates = repository.findByStateNameAndConsolidationKey(stateName,consolidationKey);
return listOfRates ;
```

Here I have applied caching logic on method, but method is not returning any values wherever I called.

Comment: What language is that? Java+Spring?

Comment: Please explain further your case

Comment: Java+ spring project

Comment: basically I want use caching on this method
findByStateNameAndConsolidationKey(String stateName,RatesConsolidationKey consolidationKey);